# Validation not working perfectly

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```js
function email() {
  var reg = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$");

  var nam = document.registration.email.value;
  var res = nam.match(reg);
  if (res) {
    alert("enter valid email");
    document.registration.email.focus();
  } else {
    document.registration.password.focus();
  }
} else {
  document.registration.email.focus();
}
}
```

```html
<form name="registration" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" onblur="email()" required />
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

The validation is not working and thus the `alert` in `if` condition is not showing. Can anyone help me to achieve this type of validation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have an extra `else`

Comment: use Jquery validation, it is easier than this. Since you have to alert the validation message all the time one by one, jquery can do it in a single stretch. If you still want to go with this please refer https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: You have one to many `}` and you have 2 `else` on one `if`

Answer (score 0):

Since You are using html 5 you don't need to write your own validation for email just use 
HTML5 has inbuilt validation check for email.

```
<form name="registration" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" onblur="email()" required />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

But in case you want to use your function anyways use it as :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function emails()
    {
            var reg=new RegExp("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$");
                var nam=document.registration.email.value;
                if(!new RegExp(reg).test(nam))
                {
                        alert(document.registration.email);
            document.registration.password.focus();
                } else {
                        document.registration.password.focus();
                }
    }

 </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="registration" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" onblur="javascript:emails()" required />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... Assuming you are trying to do some input validation for your form I suggest reading a bit regarding email validation regex. Then use something like:
https://www.regextester.com/19

Then I think your if statement is flawed. I think you meant that if the email matchs the regular expression if should focus on the password field. if the email is not empty and is invalid if should present an alert. if the email is empty it should focus on the email. I did a quick cleanup and i think the code should look something like(untested code for illustration only):

```
function validateInput() {
  var email= new RegExp("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$");
  var inputValue=document.registration.email.value;
    if(inputValue.match(email)) {
      document.registration.password.focus();
    } else if (inputValue.length > 0) {
      alert("enter valid email");
      document.registration.email.focus();
    } else {
      document.registration.email.focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

email is a reserved keyword in javascript. first rename your function email to test or whatever you want. second thing you have extra else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple errors in your javascript - syntax and dom api.

If you want to do manual validation, here is an example in a fiddle that would work.

https://jsfiddle.net/xb4qrvmy/

```
function validate_email()
{
  var reg=new RegExp("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$");

  var nam=document.forms["registration"].email.value;
  var res=nam.match(reg);
  if(!res && nam.length)
  {
    // I would advice against using alert.
    alert("enter valid email");
    document.registration.email.focus();
    // You want to somehow reset the displaying of the error.
    document.forms["registration"].email.value = ''
  } else if (res) {
    document.registration.password.focus();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate()
            {   
                        var x = document.forms["myform"]["email"].value;
                        var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
                        var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
                        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
                      alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
                          return false;
                        }
            }
            </script>
```